# Socket Server/Client with two Android devices

Tags: android, sockets, client

So I have a tablet and I want to basically make it a TCP (or UDP) Socket Server so multiple phones can send data to it. I also want to be able to send responses back to the phones. What I have so far isn't working...

Server:

```
Log.i("Server", "Starting server...");
                try {
                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    Log.i("Server", "Server status: " + ss.isBound());
                    while(true){
                        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                        Socket s = ss.accept();
                        Log.i("Server", "Server is accepting connections: " + s.isConnected());
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
                        Log.i("Server", "Initialized input and output");
                        String st = input.readLine();
                        Log.i("Server", "From client: "+st);
                        output.println("Good bye and thanks for all the fish :)");
                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And client (phone):

```
try {
                    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.106", 8080);

                    //outgoing stream redirect to socket
                    OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                    output.println("Hello Android!");
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    //read line(s)
                    String st = input.readLine();
                    tv.setText(st);
                    //Close connection
                    s.close();


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Define "isn't working"?  Stack trace, specific behavior?

Comment: The message doesn't actually send to the server until after I completely close the application on my phone.

Comment: can you add a stack trace from logcat?

Comment: Though your server side has specified "autoflush", your client side has not.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your client is not flushing the println

Try either specifying autoflush in your constructor

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
```

or manually adding a flush below your print

```
output.println("Hello Android!");
output.flush();
```