# Passing values from an android device to another

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to pass a value from an android device to another? I mean, without using the Internet. My project will be implemented only on a localhost. The two android devices are only connected through the router. If it is not possible on the local area network how can I do this? Are there other ways? I'll use the Internet or any other options if possible. Links to open source code, if you have any particularly regarding on this topic, would be appreciated too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target is Android4.0+ you can use wifi direct as @pgsandstrom stated.

In other cases if you want to make client/server comunication with two android decices you should look at this thread [Socket Server/Client with two Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825317/socket-server-client-with-two-android-devices) and the awser to this question may be usefull to you too [How to write an Android SocketServer to listen on wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054144/665823).

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict usage to Android 4.0 or later, then have a look at [wi-fi direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). It doesn't use a router thou, so I hope that isn't a restriction. If you need to support older devices, I think you have to go with bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks! and btw, does eclipse has a feature to test this function? I don't have an android 4.0 capable device